# Read access violation when attempting to delete a single node from a singly linked list C++

Tags: c++, nodes, singly-linked-list

I'm attempting to delete some nodes from a singly linked list. However, visual studio tells me that there is a read access violation in my function. I've found that it is one certain line. I've checked to make sure that I'm not deleting any of the nodes before attempting to write to them (I'm confident, though I may be wrong.) Here's the function:

```
template <class dataType>
bool UnOrderedList<dataType>::remove(int remove) {
    Node<dataType>* current = head;
    Node<dataType>* copy = head;
    Node<dataType>* trail = nullptr;

    if (current == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    if (head->data == remove) {
        Node<dataType>* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
        return true;
    }

    while (current != nullptr) {
        trail = current;
        if (current->data == remove) { // error occurs on this line
            Node<dataType>* temp2 = current;
            current = trail->next;
            delete temp2;
            return true;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return false;

}
```

I've commented on the line in which the error occurs.
Visual Studio says: "Exception thrown: read access violation.
current was 0xDDDDDDDD."

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I would love to know how I can avoid doing this in the future. I'm interested in learning more about pointers and how they work.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your error probably lies in code outside this function, which is why a [mcve] is recommended. (If you want to do more debugging on your own, I'd suggest looking at how the nodes' `next` pointers are--or are not--set.)

Answer (score 2):

When you delete a node, you don’t update the previous node’s `next` pointer.   The next time thru the loop you’ll access this dangling pointer and read memory that has been freed (which Visual C++ has set to 0xDDDDDDDD).

You need to update the previous node’s `next` pointer to the current node’s `next` pointer before deleting it, so that you skip over the node you’re deleting.

Answer (score 0):

As JaMiT mentioned, it is hard to debug without being able to reproduce. Please note a few suggestions

1. You never use `copy`.
2. The behaviour in the following part

```
while (current != nullptr) {
    trail = current;
    if (current->data == remove) { // error occurs on this line
        Node<dataType>* temp2 = current;
        current = trail->next;
        delete temp2;
        return true;
    }
    current = current->next;
}
```

does look like something you'd want to do. When you enter the loop for the first time, `trail` and `current` are the same thing (because you assign `current` to `trail`). If `current` node was not the node to be deleted, you do `current = current->next;`. Assuming this was not `nullptr`, you loop back over and set `trail` to `current` again. You may want to set `trail` to the old `current` (so that `trail` follows the `current` as the name suggests).

```
while (current != nullptr) {
    if (current->data == remove) {
        Node<dataType>* temp2 = current;//save pointer to the node to delete later
        trail->next = current->next;//skip this node - deleting it from the chain
        delete temp2;//delete it
        return true;
    }
    trail = current; //let trail follow current
    current = current->next;
}
```

3. Why does `remove` for an `UnOrderedList<dataType>` take an `int` instead of `dataType` ?

Comment: Please update your answer to correctly initialize `trail` and `current` so that your fixed code segment will work as intended.

Comment: The original code initializes `current = head` and `trail = nullptr`.  What do you think is wrong with that?

Comment: Hmm nevermind..  I guess it's dealt with earlier by testing `head` explicitly, so the first time around the loop is redundant and will fix the values.  It's not pretty code.

Comment: They should watch Linus talk about this exact thing. lol https://youtu.be/o8NPllzkFhE?t=865.